# Latin "vivere" vs. Hebrew "aviv"

Tags: latin, hebrew, cognates

Is the Latin word *vivere* (to live) cognate to the Hebrew word *aviv* אביב (Spring)? Someone pointed out the resemblance to me, and it looks plausible, but I haven't found any conclusive answer.

Comment: I'll leave it for a better historical linguist than me to give you a definitive answer, with the proper reconstructions, but I will say: very very very unlikely. The (first) 'v' in the Latin (which would have been /w/ rather than /v/ in Classical Latin anyway) goes back to Indo-European /gʷ/; while the Hebrew /v/ goes back to a /b/.

Comment: Unless you have something really strong to go on, your basic assumption should be that it's coincidental. The two words don't even have similar meanings!

Comment: This question has been marked as "off-topic: Language-specific grammar and usage questions". It is, however, not language-specific as it is about a comparison of two languages; it is also not a grammar question, nor a usage question. For this reason, I've voted to "leave open", even if on its own merits, this question should probably be closed due to lack of basic research. Make of that what you will, I'm tired of seeing this close reason being used in bogus ways.

Comment: @LjL Without a close vote reason for bad etymology questions, many of us use the top close vote reason.  It is not illegitimate because this question is not about linguistic systems, it is instead about the arbitrary coincidental vague similarity of single words in two languages. But we should change the text of the close vote reason.

Comment: @curiousdannii did you somehow never notice there is a custom close reason where you can write your own thought-out reason, and then other posters can close based on the same reason? This has been used a lot for "questions lacking basic research", so I don't see why you'd have to take the lazy route of using an *inappropriate, incorrect* reason that *won't teach the OP anything* about what thy are doing wrong. Just having gained close vote privileges doesn',  or shiuldn't, grant one the power to do things completely arbitrarily.

Comment: Additionally, I don't even think that it *is* appropriate to close this kind of questions, since they are after all about linguistics and there's nothing intrinsically inappropriate about them. They do tend to lack any basic research, which is precisely what downvotes are for. But still, voting to close with a reasonable explanation certainly beats voting to close with a bogus one.

Comment: Besides, using the "top close vote reason" is just an unreasonably *lazy* way to close a question that you think deserves closing because it's a *lazy* question where the posted failed to perform some trivial resource. Doesn't that strike you as ironic?

Comment: ... and by "where the posted failed to perform some trivial resource", I meant "where the poste**r** failed to perform some trivial res**earch**". I'm not entirely sure what my fingers do.

Comment: Why is it downvoted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Latin viv-ere "to live", viv-us "alive" is regularly derived from PIE *gweyH3- "to live, be conscious". It has nothing to do with Hebrew aviv אביב (spring). Neither phonetics nor semantics match.

Answer (score 15):

Arnaud Fournet's answer is correct: there's no evidence for a relationship. But to add a bit more evidence that there *isn't* a connection…

The Classical pronunciation of *vīvere* was something like `/wiːwɛrɛ/`, while the Biblical pronunciation of אָבִיב was something like `/ʔɑːbiːb/`. Both words are attested well before the relevant sound changes (W-hardening and beghadkephath spirantization) made them look similar.

In addition, אָבִיב is a regular formation in Hebrew. The pattern קָטִיל (*_ā_ī_*) is fairly well-attested in Hebrew for periods of time, and the root אבב (*'-b-b*) for "beginning to grow" is attested in both Hebrew and Aramaic. It's very unlikely that a loanword would fit so nicely into the Semitic root system.

Finally, *vivere* is a regular formation in Latin. It comes from the well-attested Indo-European root **gʷ-yh₃-*, with cognates in Germanic, Indo-Aryan, Hellenic, Slavic, and Celtic at least. This pretty conclusively rules out a loan into Latin.

EDIT: To drive the last nail into the coffin, Nadav Har'El has brought up Amharic አበባ (*abäba*), from the same Semitic root. This shows that the *'-b-b* root is significantly older than the Latin language itself. There could still have been some contact between an older stage of IE and an older stage of Semitic, but as you've seen, the underlying IE and Semitic roots don't look anything alike; their descendants have converged by chance.

Comment: FWIW, the major English cognate of *vivir* is *quick*. Although in modern English it tends to refer to speed, there are some archaic or technical terms like "quickening" where it retains the meaning of "alive".

Comment: Write. I'd like to add that the root "abb" is indeed an early semitic root, as evidenced by the name of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addis_Ababa, referring to a flower, in the Amharic language. When these languages split, Latin did not exist yet, so it cannot be a borrowing from Latin.

Comment: @NadavHar'El Oh, that's a fascinating bit of information! I didn't know it had any Amharic cognates; I'll update.